# How do I remove icon shaking animations in Ubuntu Dash?

Tags: ubuntu

In Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I want to disable the icon animations in Dash (I guess it's also called the launcher), e.g. skype shaking when I receive a new message.

There's a `CompizConfig` settings manager but the animations checkbox is disabled, so I don't know what else to disable.

Comment: havent u checked here?http://askubuntu.com/questions/138622/how-to-disable-all-unity-animations

Answer (score 1):

Install [compizconfig-settings-manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager)

Open Unity plugins with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and type in  `about:config` <kbd>enter</kbd>

In the CompizConfig Settings Manager:
Select the Experimental tab, and from there, select None for "Urgent Animation" and None for "Dash Blur":
[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, even after a restart the animations are still there.

Comment: Unless I also had to select "Enable Ubuntu Unity Plugin", which wasn't selected before. I'll give this a shot now..

Comment: Nah that didn't work either. Really disappointing.